# React Route with URL Param Not Updating View

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I have a react view `/wiki/:artical`. When I go from a different view to the wiki (eg from `/` to `/wiki/some-artiacal`) my view updates, but when I go from one wiki artical to another (eg `/wiki/some-artiacal` to `/wiki/some-other-artiacal`) the page does not rerender with the new content. It seems React sees them as the same view and does not rerender the page. If I refresh the browser manually the article updates, but I want react to refresh when I click `<Link to='/wiki/some-other-artiacal'></Link>`.

React Router File:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";


// COMPONENTS
import Header from './components/Header';

// VIEWS
import HomePage from './views/HomePage';
import WikiPage from './views/WikiPage';
import ProblemTesterPage from './views/ProblemTesterPage';
import NoMatchPage from './views/NoMatchPage';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <div className='container-fluid'>
        <div className='row justify-content-center'>
          <div className='col-xs-12 col-lg-8'>
            <Header/>

            <div className='card'>
                    <div className='card-body'>
                        <Switch>
                        <Route exact={true} path='/' component={HomePage}></Route>
                        <Route exact={true} path='/wiki/:artical' component={WikiPage}></Route>
                        <Route exact={true} path='/tools/problem-tester' component={ProblemTesterPage}></Route>
                        <Route component={NoMatchPage}/>
                    </Switch>
                </div>      
                </div>

                <p className='footer text-center text-secondary'>©2017 MathBrainius</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Wiki Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';

export default class HomePage extends React.Component {  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      artical: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var s = this;
    var props = s.props;

    axios.get(`/api/wiki/${props.match.params.artical}`, {
      timeout: 20000,
    })
    .then(res => {
      var ping = res.data;
      s.setState({
        artical: ping.artical
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    var s = this;
    return (
        <div>
        <ReactMarkdown source={s.state.artical}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to use `componentWillReceiveProps` to get the new `props.match.params.artical`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component is not remounting, just receiving new props so you can use the `componentWillReceiveProps` hook:

```
...

loadData(article) {
  var s = this

  axios.get(`/api/wiki/${article}`, {
    timeout: 20000,
  })
  .then(res => {
    var ping = res.data;
    s.setState({
      artical: ping.artical
    })
  })
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.loadData(this.props.match.params.artical)
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.loadData(nextProps.match.params.artical)
}

...
```

Comment: It almost works. Something is not working maybe because it is async? Basically, it is always one step behind when I switch views. If I switch between articles it gets the article from the previous article I clicked on.

Comment: Yes sorry, you need the next props. I have updated my answer. Hopefully should now work.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me so much time! Just for people viewing this in the futures can you fix `componentWillRecieveProps`? The i and the e in Receive are switched. It won't let me edit less than 6 characters.

Comment: Well spotted. I have now amended.